# How to insert 2 rows between copied data

Tags: vba, excel

I have to copy two data  from sheet1 to sheet2.
and i want to insert 2 rows between these copied data in sheet2.
But i only know that each data can contains 50 elements.
Iam stuck here. Anny idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copying the first set of data, copy the second set starting from `Worksheets("sheet2").Range(Cells(Worksheets("sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 3, 1).Address).Select`

Comment: @chrisneilsen I know there's no need but I didn't want to give him an incomplete statement that would throw and error if simply plugged into the code (arguably I could trust that OP knows enough VBA to not do that, but from the sparse information given in the question I wasn't certain)